# What is *mystifying_chebyshev* (container docker running in my server)?

Tags: docker

In my server, this container is running, but i haven't started it.

Container =>  5fc9c7a50439 **mystifying_chebyshev**

Someone knows?

Comment: How can we tell you what's running on your server? Unless specified explicitly the names are generated randomly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Containers that aren't given a name (`docker run --name`, or from compose or an orchestration tool) get named with an adjective and famous person's name according to the name generator:

https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/master/pkg/namesgenerator/names-generator.go